# Is the Limes Superior the same here?

Tags: real-analysis

Hope my question is not too stupid.

Is
$$
\limsup_n a_n/n = \limsup_n a_n/(n+1)?
$$

I would say yes because for n to infinity it does not play a role if dividing by n or n+1.

Answer (score 1):

Yes,  $\;\;\displaystyle\limsup_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_n}{n}=\limsup_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{n+1}{n}\cdot\frac{a_n}{n+1}\right)=\left(\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n+1}{n}\right)\left(\limsup_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_n}{n+1}\right)=\limsup_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_n}{n+1}$

since $\displaystyle \frac{n+1}{n}\to1>0$.